# Bootstrap resampling for stacked/ensemble leaner with mlr3 in R

Tags: r, resampling, statistics-bootstrap, mlr3

So I'm trying to generate bootstrapped resamples for an ensemble model which throws an error. This seems to result from the duplication of `row_ids`; I suppose these duplicate rows should be expected due to the resampling with replacement but I'm not sure why this fails in the ensemble context but not with a single learner.

Please see below for a reprex.

```r
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3learners)
library(mlr3pipelines)
library(progressr)
lgr::get_logger("mlr3")$set_threshold("warn")

ens.lrnr <- gunion(list(
  po("learner_cv",lrn("regr.lm")), 
  po("learner_cv",lrn("regr.rpart")))) %>>%
  po("featureunion") %>>% 
  lrn("regr.lm", id="master") |> 
  as_learner()

task <- tsk("boston_housing")
task$select(task$feature_names[! task$feature_names %in% "town"])

boot_res <- function(.lrnr) {
  progressr::with_progress(expr = {
    mlr3::resample(
      task = task,
      learner = .lrnr,
      resampling = rsmp("bootstrap", repeats = 100, ratio = 1), 
      store_models = FALSE
    )
  })
}

# single learner works
rpart_boot <- boot_res(lrn("regr.rpart"))

#ensemble learner fails
ens_boot <- boot_res(ens.lrnr)
#> Error in as_data_backend.data.frame(data, primary_key = row_ids):   
#>  Assertion on 'data[[primary_key]]' failed: Contains duplicated 
#>values, position 8.
#> This happened PipeOp regr.lm's $train()
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This looks like a bug. Could you open an issue in the [github repo](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3/) please?

Comment: Many thanks @LarsKotthoff, I've submitted an issue here: https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3/issues/903